# How to remove log4j dependency in slf4j

Tags: java, security, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am working to fix any log4j dependency on my project. I looked for references of log4j in the dependency tree and I could only find this **org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.32:runtime**. How do I confirm whether this dependency is fine or not, If someone can help.

Comment: That lib is an adapter, you can ignore it. `log4j-core` is the affected library. If you don't have that, you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

slf4j is safe from the log4shell vulnerability: http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html

Comment: It says in the link it is safe to use log4j-over-slf4j.jar in conjunction with the SLF4J API unless underlying implementation is log4j 2.x. How could I check the version of log4j?